# JavaFX - graph, which is generated on the server side, cant show values

Tags: java, graph, javafx

When i generate image on the server side using JavaFX, i cant see any values on the axis. Labels, legend even graph are displayed,but not the values . When i try it on local with same values, everthing is ok. I changed font, called every possible method (as setAutorRange, setLowerBound ... etc) still without success.

Image from server:

[image]

Image from app:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: JavaFX is a UI technology, that is not intended for use in a headless application (like on a server). This might cause troubles, that should manifest themselves in exceptions.

Comment: JavaFX does fully support off-screen rendering of it's scene graph.  @hotzst is implying there may be exceptions being thrown during the off-screen render which would explain why part of the chart is rendered but not all.  You may not see the exception thrown to the server console if you have the rendering in a runLater() thread.  
What version of Java are you using?
Are you generating the charts under  a separate thread?
Aree you attempting to apply CSS styles to your chart?  (this is a semi-common cause of runtime exceptions, if the resource cannot be located etc)

Comment: indeed, but i started separated JavaFX Application Thread, so i thought that will be ok. It can genarete even more complex graph with hundreds of inputs, but cant show any values

Comment: @Birdasaur i am aplying CSS style with succes, just a colour of series( just uploaded image is without because i was despared, and i thought same way as you) . You are right,  i run it through runlater.  I am using Java 8-65. on JBoss EAP 6.4.0

Comment: Ok that's good info.  If you are throwing an exception within that runLater you might not see it on the JBoss logger unless you are specifically try/catching for it. Unless you are setup to debug that runLater with a breakpoint, I would wrap that code with a try/catch block for a generic Exception type.  Wrap the entire runLater() block if you can just to be sure you are not throwing some odd exception.  Make sure there are no null variables.  I'm not an expert at JBoss but I'm wondering if that class loader is not locating your CSS resource the same way as a standard app.

Comment: i alraedy have runLater block in try/catch. But i create chart in own class, and there i have try/catch block only when i am setting data. Both without any exceptions.

Comment: ok, so here is the answer. Linechart is animated as default, so when i did snapshot i had to call chart.setAnimated(false].

Comment: Thanks Bidrasaur for effort